# Android Studio Giraffe prevents Windows from going into sleep mode

Tags: android-studio, hibernation

I'm sorry if this is posted in the wrong forum, but I have a problem with **Android Studio Giraffe**, currently version **2022.3.1 patch 2**. I updated to Android Studio Giraffe just over a month ago and ever since I did my computer (**Windows 10**) wont go in to sleep mode. I don't know if it is the emulator or just Android Studio that prevents it, but when I exit Android Studio my computer will in fact still go into sleep.

It was not like this in the previous version of Android Studio that I used. I didn't notice it until I got my power bill which was $50 higher than usual. I hoped that I would avoid these kinds of problems by postponing the update to Giraffe for a while for them to work out the kinks since a previous update lead to me not being able to work for weeks due to bugs.

As an entrepreneur living on my savings this is devastating for me financially and I hope I can fix it with some settings. I can't be the only one with this problem, but I haven't found the right phrasing to get any good suggestions via google. Of course I could turn off the computer manually everytime I leave for more than 10 minutes, but it takes time to start up the computer and the entire environment I work in so I much prefer the computer just goes to sleep when I leave it be.

Has anybody else had the same problem and perhaps have some good suggestions on how to solve this?